# Map Marker not showing up

Tags: java, sqlite, google-maps

I am trying to use a database to add a map marker to my map and it is not showing up for some reason. The camera is moving to the location but the map marker is not being placed. Please explain to me how i can solve this problem.
This is my code from my map activity:

```
 private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title){
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
        DataBaseHelper myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        List<LatLng> lls = myDb.getAllLatLng();

        for (LatLng ll: lls){

            LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(ll.latitude, ll.longitude);

            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(coordinates)
                    .title(title)
                    .snippet(showDetails.getText().toString());

            mMap.addMarker(options);
            myDb.close();

        }
```

This is my data base code:

```
public List<LatLng> getAllLatLng(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                double x,y;
                x = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(4));
                y = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(5));
                LatLng ll= new LatLng(x,y);
                // Adding contact to list
                latLngs.add(ll);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        return latLngs;
    }
```

Thanks